# Redirect to anothe page using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect the url of **`http://sitename/modules/fb/fb.php`** to **`http://sitename/modules/take_control`** .How can i do that using htaccess

I tried like

**`RewriteRule ^/?modules/fb/fb\.php$ take_control`** , Is that right ?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is the opposite of what you **most likely** want if you are trying to rewrite to take_control.

Give this a try. These rules should provide the rewrite with `take_control` as the URI both ways.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /+modules/fb/fb\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /take_control/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^take_control/?$ /modules/fb/fb.php [L]
```

Comment: `most likely` = `definitely` :) ++